# What is a nontrivial graph?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I've been operating happily under the definition that a nontrivial graph is a graph with at least two vertices for some time.

Today I came upon a source which defined a nontrivial graph as a graph with one or more edges.

Now I have all my ruffles in a bunch.

What is the most widely accepted definition of a nontrivial graph?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, since you can check quite easily which of the possible "trivial graphs" would satisfy the property in question.

Comment: I vote for the single vertex one.  For otherwise, you could say stuff as "an independent set in a graph is a set of vertices that induce a trivial graph", which confuses me.

Comment: @ManuelLafond I agree.  I use empty graph to mean a graph without edges, and therefore a nonempty graph would be a graph with at least one edge.

Comment: According to both wikipedia.com and wikibooks.com, a *trivial* graph is a graph with 1 vertex and 0 edges.